# CPU not utilising all cores

Tags: windows, cpu, intel-core-i3, cpu-z

Task manager and CPU-Z show that my Intel Core i3-4150 only has one core and two threads. When it should be two and four. The only program I have used that might have impacted this is VirtualBox (I have restarted the PC since using it).

What are some of the possible solutions for fixing this?

[image: CPU-Z Screenshot]

Comment: Would you mind extending your question by a screenshot of CPU-Z? This will likely help others to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, just added an image of the CPU display, not really sure what's relevant.

Comment: Here is Intel's product page for the mentioned CPU: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/77486/intel-core-i3-4150-processor-3m-cache-3-50-ghz.html

Comment: If you go to the CPU tab of the Resource Monitor, do you see CPU 2 and 3 in the right pane?

Comment: In the right pane there is CPU 0 and CPU 1, both of which are showing usage.

Comment: Neat problem.  Update the BIOS for your motherboard.  Also check if they have a CPU support list.

Comment: Using a B85M-D3H. Oh boy, BIOS flashes are always fun.Thanks.

Comment: Windows 10??????

Comment: Yeah I've been using Windows 10 @Moab

Answer (score 1):

Newer Intel CPU's support Core Parking, which effectively stops some cores to safe energy if they are not needed. Try to start up a few more programs and observe if the other Core gets activated. If this does not help, try to set Window's Power Plan Settings to High Performance. This should also disable the parking.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
After running the bios it seems to have automatically fixed it. Didn't even need to flash the motherboard.Thanks for the help.